# PHP - Calling abstract class child method only once?

Tags: php, oop

I'm new to OOP programming and am in the process of creating a settings page and extending various abstract classes.

I have created two ***abstract*** classes **admin_setting** and **theme_admin_setting (extends admin_setting)** which itself has two extended classes: (not abstract) **setting_news** and **setting_buttons** with very similar functionality but different form fields outputted on the page.

Each button/news item is then able to be added to and removed on the settings page by javascript and then on submit it is all saved to the database.

When adding a new button/news item (in the JS) as the form fields are different it gets a bit messy so I wanted to pass some variables to the script to make the code a bit cleaner.

The problem arose when I wanted to pass Javascript some values in a script tag but only wanted to do this once per instance of each extended class.

For example:

**setting_news:**

```
<script>var news_array = <?php echo $news_array... </script>
```

**setting_buttons:**

```
<script>var button_array = <?php echo $button_array... </script>
```

But each time the class is instantiated (about 10 times per page) it obviously outputs the script tag and I wanted to keep the code tidy so to only do it once.

Is the answer perhaps to create another abstract class one deeper than theme_admin_setting with a counter function within that?

Comment: **Don't** do any processing in the class constructor. Its only purpose is to construct the object and prepare it for work. This means only initialization of the fields; nothing else. Put the actual work (no matter if it's just output or more complex processing) into methods. Call the appropriate method(s) in the appropriate place(s) to get the job done.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to build an overall array of all buttons and news (e.g. `array( 'news' => array( 'news one', 'news two', ...), 'buttons' => array( ... ) );`), rebuilding it as JSON and add this to the script tag and parse it? For that you could add a get method to your abstract class, which get's each type of setting as an array. In your code, which created the classes you can build this overall array with foreach, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can have `public static $isCalled = false;` inside each extended class and than when calling function just do

```
if (!self::$isCalled) {
    self::$isCalled = true;
    /* do your code */
}
```

Comment: This obviously gives me an error: Access to undeclared static property: theme_admin_setting::$isCalled when I call it in **theme_admin_setting**. Is there a way of having it in there or do I have to put a function in each extended class?

Comment: @MarkMcDermid How do you declare your `$isCalled` property?

Comment: `public static $isCalled = false;` in **setting_news** & **setting_buttons**

Comment: Note I am trying to call it in **theme_admin_setting** : their parent abstract class

Comment: @MarkMcDermid You can't access child class properties from parent class. That's why it's not working.